# PYTHONPATH set when loading Idle in virtual environment

Tags: python, pythonpath

How can I setup things so that the PYTHONPATH is set to a particular project, and all the virtual environment modules are available when Idle is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append it to environment like so:

```
import sys
if "N:/ProjectX/Scripts" not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append("N:/ProjectX/Scripts")
```

**Edit:** you can install `PyYaml` package to your python with `pip`, then make `Default_Path.yaml` somewhere in your main application directory and insert your project and paths like so:

```
 #Paths
 ProjectX:
     Icon: 'N:/ProjectX/ICON'
     Presets: 'N:/ProjectX/Presets'
 ProjectY:
     Icon: 'N:/ProjectY/ICON'
     Presets: 'N:/ProjectY/Presets'
```

and to read `Default_Path.yaml` you can run this:

```
import yaml
documents = open(N:/Application/Default_Path.yaml, 'r')
doc = yaml.load(documents) #It's a Dictionary
print doc['ProjectX']['Icon']
```

then you can check with users system and if the path doesn't exists append them to their environment.

**Edit:** reading sub-python files in a python project is simply by organize and add `__init__.py` in every sub-folders like so:

```
D:/ #Driver name
    projectX/ #Project Name
        main.py #Main Application
        Mudules/ #Sub-folder
            __init__.py #initialize the sub-folder
            module1.py #package/moudle
            module2.py #package/moudle
        Widgets/ #Sub-folder
            __init__.py #initialize the sub-folder
            widget1.py #custom widget 
            widget2.py #custom widget
```

visual example:
[image]

I give my main file `main.py` because of c++, but in python you can give any name, it's personal preference.

and to call your sub-python project in your `main.py`, you just write like so:

```
import Mudules.module1 as moudle1
import Widgets.widget1 as coolUI
```

or

```
from Mudules.module1 import *
from Widgets.widget1 import *
```

Then you just call you function. and you don't need to check if the path is in `sys.path` and if not `sys.path.append()` for python files.

Comment: I am looking for a solution that does not require a lot of typing. Right now I have to type 6 long lines to get the environment setup for my project.

Comment: @Jonathan you can make YAML file of projects with their paths and a function to load them on your environment base on your project number. if that's not what you want maybe you give more details.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. My primary development envirionment is Eclipse with Pydev and I only use Idle for checking out potential problems in a simple environment. Accordingly, I am looking for a very simple solution but it appears that it may not exist. Many thanks.

Comment: @Jonathan i think you are talking about importing python files in a specific python project right? i thought you are talking about loading path of none python project. that's quite simple let me edit my answer and explain it there.